# c++ print/read to/from text file - hex value and 4 integers and read them and separate data accordingly

Tags: c++, string, io, getline

hi i have a maze solving bot which opens doors using hex keys ( e.g 0xFA25 ) when it opens a door using said key, if the key works and the door opens i would like it to print the room name followed by the direction the door is in, followed by the key itself so i can hardcode it.

e.g format of writing to file would be as follows : 2Y35 2 0x200F

i have no problems storing the name/location of the room as i have 3 integers i can write, same with the direction,  the issue i have is how i can print a hex value, e.g i tried printing the values before and they came out as like 195151 ( not sure if thats the resulting number of said hex value stored ) but since i need to also read the hex value back into the system i need it formatted as its 4 digit hex value ( e.g 0xFA25 ).

the other issue is how would i get the bot to read the line : 2Y35 2 0x200F  ( for example )
and sort the line into  Level = 2, (ignore Y), North/south = 3, east/west = 5 direction = 2 key = 200F

no code i can post here will make it any clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

funnily enough i solved it, clearly i didnt look through my old questions well enough, used istringstream to seperate it out, however didnt format it as e.g 2Y03 1 FF2A , its more formatted as : 2 0 3 1 65322

the way i stored it was

```
used_keys << level << ' ' << ns << " " << ew << " " << direction << " " << key << std::endl;
```

and the way i read it was

```
while (getline(used_keys, line)) {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            int level;
            int ns;
            int ew;
            int direction;
            int key;

            // this splits the string with the delimiter of whitespace

            iss >> level >> ns >> ew >> direction >> key;

            room_id[level][ns][ew].used_keys[direction] = key;
            printf("STORED KEY - %6d\n", room_id[level][ns][ew].used_keys[direction]);
        }
```

bot works perfectly, only saves key to file if it didnt already read it from the file, hope this helps someone if they are looking for the same string splitting i was